# Fedex Shipping method is not showing up on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

I obtained the key, password, account id and meter number from FedEx and then enabled FedEx shipping method from Magento backend using that information. But After Adding the product into cart, FedEx shipping method is not showing up on frontend. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Please check the shipping origion and shipping destination.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that you have FedEx turned on at both the website and store level? Also, do your products have weights assigned to them?

Comment: Yes it is enabled. And my products also have weights.

Comment: What do you mean by check origin and destination? it have origin and destination.

Comment: Admin -> Configuration - > shipping settings - > shipping Origin
You can check the allowd Conuntry settings
You can also enable "Show Method if Not Applicable" to Yes, and confirm if the rates are not available for the selected destination, try with different destination address

Comment: Pravin i changed the origin from United States to Pakistan. Now it is showing FedEx Shipping method on frontend. But it is also showing an error "This shipping method is not available, please specify ZIP-code".

Comment: https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/standalone?method=goToPackageInfoPage , you need to  check the rates here , if fedex is providing service to the the provided zipcode , then only it will show the rates , otherwise it might be possible that Fedex is not providing service to those locations , you can try setting US and origin and check with some us state and you can confirm that whether the issue in is fedex or your locations Thanks

Comment: Pravin, i got anothoer problem. The issue has been resolved in magento 1.8 but i have another installation of magento 1.9 in which fedex shipping method is not showing up on frontend. I set the origin too. But it is still not working on 1.9. Can you please help me on this? Thank You pravin.

Comment: Give me the exact version of your magento and source and destination zip code and weight , i will check if the rates are loading for this source and destination or not . Have you tried for different US location ? If no , Please enable the log from admin and check the error log, There might be some issue with the fedex credentials as well

Comment: What was the issue by the way

Comment: I am facing the same issue in magneto 1.9.2. On frontend error is thrown saying **This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.Fedex**  I check all details  many times.

Comment: is it solve your problem,

Answer (score 0):

You can try function `die('something');` inside its class and see if the page dies or not. If not, it mean the method has been disabled somewhere

Comment: where to put die(); in fedEx block

Comment: I use it as a function for debugging, like a break point. You can put it anywhere to see if it is called or not. If it is called, then the page will stop loading. Otherwise, the program doesn't go there yet.